# net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@4013f648 appears in the response of JDBC request in Jmeter

Tags: database, jdbc, jmeter

I am using JDBC request sampler in jmeter and trying to fetch some data from the database.

**Sql statement**:- SELECT TOP 1 auditInfo,comments,EntityId FROM t_audit_log where EntityType='Contact' and OpType='Contact created' ORDER BY AuditId DESC

**Parameter Types**:- String,String,String
**Variable Names**:- auditInfo,comments

pfa [JDBC Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8CKk.png) for the JDBC request sampler.

But when I run this sampler in jmeter i got below response:--

**auditInfo**=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@4013f648                                       **EntityId**=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ClobImpl@5e8e11d5

pfa [JDBCSampler Respnse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjoCa.png)

The problem is with the datatype of the auditinfo and EntityId cols.In database the datatype for auditinfo col is ntext and EntityId is varchar(max).
and In Jmeter it is returning the clob objects for both.
I am using jmeter 2.11.
How to solve this issue.Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can try another driver, i.e. [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) to see if the response will be String-based.
2. You can keep using the current driver and amend your JDBC URL like:

   > jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://foo;**useLOBs=false**;DatabaseName=bar

   so the driver will return the values as Strings (`useLOBs` property is [`true` by default](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html))
3. And finally  can use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to fetch data from CLOB objects using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripting, check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for details on how to do this.